# Difference between strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE" and empty

Tags: jpa

From the two syntax, A and B. Is there any performance change, if not put strategy attribute In 'A' statement.

A)

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "titleListMapSeq" ,strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "titleListMapSeq", sequenceName = "title_list_map_seq")
private Long id;
```

B)

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "titleListMapSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "titleListMapSeq", sequenceName = "title_list_map_seq")
private Long id;
```

Comment: The title and the question are asking different things, please clarify

Comment: generally , already there is a SequenceGenerator, here is the case, so if i put strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE then what happened.is SequenceGenerator ignored or anthing..i am confused..please clarify me.what if it exist or not

Comment: If you put SEQUENCE then it uses the named "SequenceGenerator" of the same name as what the `GeneratedValue` specifies. BUT if the database does not support SEQUENCEs then it is all ignored ...

Comment: @NeilStockton what you mean in reverse , if i dont put SEQUENCE  then it NOT uses the named "SequenceGenerator"

Comment: Somebody has already answered what happens if you don't put SEQUENCE ... it uses AUTO ... so you get what your JPA provider feels like doing.

Comment: @NeilStockton , just dont rely on basic poing. There is already SequenceGenerator exist.If there is no SequenceGenerator , then it goes to AUTO. I am not asking basics right

Comment: No idea what a "basic poing" is, so suggest that you go back to your question and rewrite it so that it is clear what you are asking. Like the first comment above asked you to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same , if you put @SequenceGenerator , it will by default calls "strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the JPA provider.
As shown in [Javadoc for GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html), the strategy parameter is optional and defaults to [javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO):

> Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database. The AUTO generation strategy may expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to create one. A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such resources in the event that it does not support schema generation or cannot create the schema resource at runtime.